# подключение БД к php

Tags: php, mysql

Я создал БД Persons, и в нем таблица Information. Сейчас я хочу эту базу подключить к php, как это сделать не понятно. Я пользуюсь docker-ом, и у меня оперативная система mac os

Comment: Как-то так: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 1):

> я хочу эту базу подключить к php

Подключить базу можно примерно так:

`$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','логин','пасс','Persons') or die(mysqli_error($db));`

Про такую так называемую 'оперативную систему' я не в курсе.